# Drawing part of a path in METAFONT

Tags: metafont

In METAFONT, is there a way to draw part of a path?
If I have the programme

```
mode_setup;
  em#:=10pt#;

define_pixels(em);

beginchar("a",em#,em#,0);
z1=(0,0); z2=(w,h);
pickup pencircle scaled .2pt;
path p;
p = z1{right}..z2;
draw p;
endchar;

end
```

Can I draw 80% of the path `p` and stop short?

(What made me wonder is that I was considering how one might draw a `C`
for the logo font (used to typeset `METAFONT`).  I thought it might be
done by stopping short of a full `O`.  Perhaps the are better ways.)

Comment: Metapost has AFAIK a `subpath` construction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @marmot's comment,

```
draw subpath (0,.8) of p;
```